# Fbprophet installation error - failed to setup

Tags: python

When I wanted to install Fbprophet, I got the error message. Please help.

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft
>   Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
>
> Command "C:\Users\Ekin\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Ekin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-18154lmz\pystan\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\Ekin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-73_kkd1_\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Ekin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-18154lmz\pystan\

Comment: Did you try to do what the error message says?

Comment: I setup Microsoft Visual C++ but I have the same error already.